# how to make row collapsible in angular js using ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I am using ng-repeat in my project .I am able to print my objects in row .Actually I want  only display element present in dom so I used this plugin
https://github.com/kamilkp/angular-vs-repeat
My issue is that there is space between rows .I need to remove space between row.I don’t for where this space come .
here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/Gtdi7QjO2vdtfyF6BUCd?p=preview

```
 <div vs-repeat class="repeater-container">
          <div class="row" ng-repeat="column in invoice_records " ng-class-odd="'odd-row'">
            <div class="col brd collapse-sm" ng-repeat="field in column.columns" ng-show="invoice_column_name[$index].checked && invoice_column_name[$index].fieldNameOrPath===field.fieldNameOrPath">{{field.value}}</div>
            <div class="col col-10 text-center brd collapse-sm"></div>
          </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space is coming due to fixed "top" property. If you change them, then the space between rows can be increased or decreased.

Edit: The actual problem was due to margin and padding. Added a new class to reset them.

"http://plnkr.co/edit/PqSmlAuAF25kFid8V7jW?p=preview" is the plnkr for the same.

```
.new-class{
  margin-top : 0px;
  padding-top : 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Here is the changed HTML:

```
<div class="row new-class" ng-repeat="column in invoice_records " ng-class-odd="'odd-row'">
```

Comment: how I will change ..!! Actually It is coming dynamically

Comment: You have these options: 1) Add a class to each div and define the styles particular to the class in the css. 2) Use inline styles, though it is discouraged. 3) Change the styles using jquery/ javascript if possible.

Comment: of you know please make a plunker

Comment: Sure give me some time.

Comment: Code is too vast, I am trying to find the source of it.

Comment: Got the solution, posting it in 2 minutes

Comment: "http://plnkr.co/edit/PqSmlAuAF25kFid8V7jW?p=preview". Here I have added a "new-class" to the html having ng-repeat and in the css file, I have removed the margin and padding, that solved your problem, check it.

Comment: please look this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776568/how-to-use-collection-repeat-instead-of-ng-repeat

Comment: Sorry I don't have any idea about collection-repeat.