# why list is not display while using collection-repeat instead of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I used ng -repeat in my demo .But due to large data coming from service .I want to use  collection-repeat for performance better .how I will use collection-repeat  to get the same out put here .here is my plunker

```
<ion-scroll scrollbar-y="true" delegate-handle="i" ng-style="viewHeight">
          <div class="row" ng-repeat="column in i | limitTo: counter  track by $index" ng-class-odd="'odd-row'">
            <div class="col brd collapse-sm" ng-repeat="field in column.columns" ng-show="i[$index].checked && i[$index].f===field.fieldNameOrPath">{{field.value}}</div>
            <div class="col col-10 text-center brd collapse-sm"></div>
          </div>
        </ion-scroll>
        <ion-infinite-scroll immediate-check="false" on-infinite="loadMore(query)" distance="10%"></ion-infinite-scroll>
```

here I am trying to use collection repeat  like that

But not getting same result

can we use thin grid view ?

Comment: have you seen this, looks like it may be a bug with collection repeats set height thing. http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/bug-in-grid-usage-of-collection-repeat/10331/4

Comment: could you please give some solution ..how I will acheive this

Comment: so you have <div collection-repeat=""></div> try adding item-height="200" so you end up with <div collection-repeat="your repeat items here" item-hegith="200">. pretty much you can play around with item-height and item-width and hopefully get it to work. Take a look at the docs here http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/collectionRepeat/

Comment: Plunker link missing?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you were able to find the answer by now but just in case, hopefully this will help...

Collection repeat does not support "`limitTo: counter  track by $index`"

Please let me know if you are still having issues.